# Rails Nested File Upload: Edit Content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I built an ajax upload form for image uploads with RoR which works well so far. The only problem I am facing is when editing content that has images attached to it. I want the images to show up as thumbnails (no problem) and below that a new upload field.

This is how I show the upload field normally in the view...

```
<%= form.fields_for :images do |builder|%>
   <p><%= builder.label :image %></p>
   <p id="ajax_upload"><%= builder.file_field :image %></p>
<% end %>
```

If I do this for editing content I get as many upload fields as images.. I just want one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally do not refer to symbols for form builders, as they tend to behave in unexpected ways sometimes. You should be able to send in an object instance like so:

```
<% @image = @the_model.images.first %>
<%= form.fields_for @image do |builder|%>
   <p><%= builder.label :image %></p>
   <p id="ajax_upload"><%= builder.file_field :image %></p>
<% end %>
```